# Зачем надо указывать @namespace в представлениях?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Мы указываем пространство имен с помощью @using, а для чего тогда надо использовать @namespace? Какая практическая от этого польза, за исключением того, что файл в WebApp\obj\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Razor\Views будет иметь указанное пространство имен?

[image: Код]

Comment: Впервый раз вижу чтобы в представление добавлялся namespace, это какая версия asp.net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> файл в Views будет иметь указанное пространство имен

Это и есть основная польза. В случае, когда views [выносятся в отдельный проект или пакет](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio), `@namespace` позволяет контролировать имена классов в этом проекте.

Если не рассматривать случай выноса - может быть некоторые `@using`-и при прямом указании namespace можно не писать.